# can not loop through $slots object in Vue 3 to pass all slots from parent to child

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, quasar-framework, vuejs-slots

I can not loop through the $slots object in Vue 3 to pass all slots from parent to child, the $slots object seems empty in the child component.

How can I loop through the $slots object to pass all parent slots to the child component?

I get this error when I run the code:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'key')

[image: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'key')]

Here is a sandbox about my problem and you can uncomment line 5 to see the complete result:
https://codesandbox.io/s/blazing-bush-g7c9h?file=/src/pages/Index.vue

GitHub sample:
https://github.com/firibz/vue3slots

parent:

```
<system-input filled v-model="text" label="input">
  <template v-slot:before>
    <q-icon name="mail" />
  </template>
</system-input>
```

child:

```
  <div class="row justify-center">
    <q-input v-model="componentValue" v-bind="$attrs" style="width: 250px">
      <template v-for="(_, slot) of $slots" v-slot:[slot]="scope">
        <slot :name="slot" v-bind="scope"/>
      </template>
    </q-input>
    <q-separator class="full-width" color="secondary" />
    <div class="bg-negative full-width q-pa-lg">slots: {{ $slots }}</div>
    <div class="bg-warning full-width q-pa-lg">slots: {{ $slots.before }}</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Your code works fine in this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/quasar-starter-ehpety?file=src%2FApp.vue).

Comment: @tony19 your demo is the only place that this code works and I can not understand what is the difference. this code is not working in my demo and is not working in any of my projects.

Comment: Can you share a link to a GitHub project that reproduces the problem?

Comment: @tony19 here is a [git repository](https://github.com/firibz/vue3slots), you can also download the provided sample on codesandbox,

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to use Object.keys($slots) in order to use slots on v-for.

```
<q-input v-model="componentValue" v-bind="$attrs" style="width: 250px">
  <template v-for="(slot, index) of Object.keys($slots)" :key="index" v-slot:[slot]>
    <slot :name="slot"></slot>
  </template>
</q-input>
```

Comment: This works, but throughs a Typescript error: "Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string | number' can't be used to index type 'Readonly<...". Does anyone know a way around this error without ignoring it?

Answer (score 2):

To prevent TypeScript errors in the template you can get and cast the slot names in the setup.

Ideally, you could get the actual types rather than just cast to 'default'

```html
<template
  v-for="(slot, index) of slotNames"
  :key="index"
  #[slot]
>
  <slot :name="slot" />
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
import { useSlots } from "vue";


const slots = useSlots();

// Assert type here to prevent errors in template
const slotNames = Object.keys(slots) as "default"[];

</script>
```

Comment: For some reason your solution did not work for me, but this solution removed all the errors in template: `const slotNames = Object.keys(slots) as unknown` I will probably also wrap it in computed just in case slots change, I don't know if this is necessary: `const slotNames = computed<unknown>(() => Object.keys(slots) as unknown)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using Vuetify Playground to [demonstrate Vue 3 dynamic slot/template pass through](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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):

```html
    <template #[name] v-for="slot, name in $slots">
      <slot :name="name"></slot>
    </template>
```

[image]