# passing vue slot in child component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs-slots

Is there a possibility to access the Vue slot in a deeper nested child component like this?

```
<Parent>
    <Child1>
        <Child2>
            Content
        </Child2>
    </Child1>
</Parent>
```

I want to pass HTML to a deeper child component from the parent component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using [scoped slots](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Scoped-Slots) we can iterate over the slots and pass them down

notice the `child-slot` name;

```
# Parent
<template>
  <Child1>
    <template v-slot:child-slot>
     Content
    </template>
  </Child1>
</template>

# Child 1

<template>
   <Child2>
     <template v-for="(index, name) in $scopedSlots" v-slot:[name]="data">
       <slot :name="name" v-bind="data"></slot>
     </template>
  </Child2>
</template>

# Child 2

<template>
  <div>
     <slot name="child-slot">Fallback Content</slot>
   </div>
 </template>
```

Answer (score 0):

#### VueJS 3 solution

@xyos' answer doesn't work with Vue 3 due to some [extensive changes](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/slots-unification.html) but it put me on the right track...  After quite a bit of searching, I discovered a (slightly more cumbersome) solution; replacing the `Child1` excerpt above:

```html
<template>
   <Child2>
      <template v-for="(slot, index) of Object.keys($slots)" :key="index" v-slot:[slot]>
         <slot :name="slot"></slot>
      </template>
   </Child2>
</template>
```

Full credit to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71983325/645016).