# Dynamically switch between component or `template`

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, fragment

So I have a complex Vue monorepo setup which involves some apps running in Vue2 and some other running in Vue3.

In the monorepo I also got some packages which sometimes expose components (to be consumed by both Vue2 and Vue3 with `vue-demi`).

The problem is that for some technical requirements I need to have some components defined as a `fragment` within a table (Several nodes under `template`), some of it related to a11y . I know that [vue3 already allows this](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/new/fragments.html) but in vue2 is not possible.

So I was tempted to use [`vue-frag`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-frag) for the vue2 side. What is the issue? That library is not compatible with vue3.

So my question is, is there a possibility to switch between the `template`'s vue3 tag and `Fragment` from `vue-frag` ?

Something like:

```js
  // This actually does not work, because it try to interpret template as an HTML tag
 <component :is="isVue2 ? Fragment : 'template'>
   <-- ... --/>
 </component>
```

Comment: Use v-if and two <component>, I guess. This could be extracted to your own fragment component. You will have more flexibility with render functon.

Comment: Really wanted to avoid doing the v-if, because that requires quite some code duplication

Comment: Depends on your case. As said, you can create your own frag comp that does this to avoid duplication

Comment: How to create my own frag comp for vue3?

Comment: See the first comment. And pass slots and props if needed, it's something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71052398/can-not-loop-through-slots-object-in-vue-3-to-pass-all-slots-from-parent-to-chi